# Jquery value of attribute

Tags: jquery

I need help retrieving an attribute from a  element using jquery.

```
<a id="status" shop="10" shopstatus="30" href="#" " title="onu" data-shop-id="9" bindingid="1000"><img src="myimg.jpg"></a>
```

This is the code so far

```
var rowStatus = $(r).find('td#status').attr('shopstatus');
```

I want the result to be "30" when running the query. Can somebody help me?

Comment: You are not targeting the `a` element!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `a` tag is nested in a `td` tag:

```
var rowStatus = $(r).find('td #status').attr('shopstatus');
```

This `td#status` would match `<td id="status"></td>`.

This `td #status` would match `<td><a id="status"></a></td>`.

Comment: Yes it is in a td, maybe should've mentioned that. The var r prints out the correct row but rowStatus is undefined. Your suggestion solved it. Omg